# ASP.NET MVC how to display associative data based on id's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to display data on my index view from from my models that are associated with each other based on id's. I.e. display client name, asset name that belongs to this client, and address of this client, etc...

Here's my model:

Client model:

```
 public class Client : Person {

    public ICollection<OccupancyHistoryRecord> OccupancyRecords { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RentHistoryRecord> RentRecords { get; set; }
}
```

Asset model:

```
  public class Asset {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Asset Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Asset Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public FullAddress Address { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Asking Rent")]
    public string AskingRent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OccupancyHistoryRecord> OccupancyRecords;

    public ICollection<RentHistoryRecord> RentRecords;

}
```

Occupancy Record:

```
public class OccupancyHistoryRecord {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AssetId { get; set; }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Client Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
        var clients = db.Clients.Include(c => c.OccupancyRecords) // how to get the asset name instead of the id)
            .Include(c => c.HomeAddress)
            .Include(c => c.WorkAddress);
        return View(clients.ToList());
 }
```

Index View:

```
@model IEnumerable<RentalManagement.Models.Client>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OccupancyRecords)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HomeAddress) 
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WorkAddress)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OccupancyRecords)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HomeAddress.StreetAddress)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkAddress.StreetAddress)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }, null) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Assets", "Details", "Assets", new { id = item.Id}, null) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Right now it's displaying the occupancy record's Id. What I want is to display the asset name based on the occupancy's AssetId.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var clients = db.Clients.Include(c => c.OccupancyRecords) // how to get the asset name instead of the id)
        .Include(c => c.HomeAddress)
        .Include(c => c.WorkAddress);
    return View(clients.ToList());
}
```

code as below:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
{
    var clients = db.Clients.Include(c => c.OccupancyRecords.Select(s => new { AssetId = s.AssetId, AssetName = /* Find AssetName  By Id here */ }))  
        .Include(c => c.HomeAddress)
        .Include(c => c.WorkAddress);
    return View(clients.ToList());
}
```